# I have restored my .claws-mail folder but c-w still presents the first run wizard and ignores my settings

Tags: linux, email, claws-mail

I'm using Linux Mint 19 and have been backing up daily with BackInTime.  On previous occasions when I have restored files claws-mail has re-opened just as I left it.

On this occasion it keeps presenting me with the first run wizard and ignores my existing rc files.

I'm guessing that there's a file which tells it that there is no pre-existing configuration, but don't know what that is.  Can anyone help?  I don't want to lose all my filters and rules!

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it.  Although all my original config files were present I had to let the wizard run.  I just accepted all the options it offered (even though these were not correct) and then when it completed the new (nonsense) mailbox and my originals were there.  I deleted the nonsense mailbox and now everything is OK.